# Is it good to disable DH keypair?

Tags: java, cryptography, tls1.2, diffie-hellman

I had the following exception when running a java code `'Could not generate DH keypair'` (I use TLSv1.2).

I  transformed the prime size from **1024** to **2048** but I always get the same error.

Then **I disabled DH**, and it worked perfectly.

But, is it good to disable DH? does it effect security? And when can we disable it?

Comment: You need to provide more details, such as the class and function you were using, and which options you used then and now. Generally DH stands for the diffie hellman key exchange, which provides perfect forward secrecy. It typically negatively affects the security of your application to disable it, but whether it actually does or not depends on your threat model

Comment: Please provide full stack traces and any info / changes on your runtime configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> But, is it good to disable DH?

That depends on the situation. Generally ECDH (Diffie Hellman using elliptic curves instead of finite groups) is still available. Although that is slightly more vulnerable to quantum cryptanalysis, it generally increases security levels.

> does it effect security?

See above. You'd lose *forward security* if you have to rely on `RSA_` modes.

> And when can we disable it?

See above. Generally I'd disable it and make sure that ECDHE_ ciphersuites are available.

---

I'd be worried though if I didn't know *why* it would not be able to run. This could point to a badly configured software configuration.